# Iterating recursively in alphabetic, depth-first order?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

How do I iterate through a folder so that I respect the alphabetic (lexical) order, but recurse into any directories before moving on to the next item of the old directory?

Sample structure for clarification:

```
Alpha
  |- 1.txt
  |- 2.txt
  |- 3
  |  |- a.txt
  |  \- b.txt
  \- 4.txt
Beta
  \- Test
     \- Another
        \- File.txt
```

I'd like to iterate in such a way that, were I were to print all the items that came by, the result would look as follows:

```
Alpha
1.txt
2.txt
3
a.txt
b.txt
4.txt
Beta
Test
Another
File
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to properly do both the recursion and the ordering without making a really nasty mess of nested `Get-ChildItem` with manual recursion, but I am hopeful that there is a neater way that I can also learn from.

If this is too difficult to implement for some reason, reserving the order at which the items are processed is the bottom line of what matters to me as I can make do without preserving the tree structure if I have to.

Comment: don't do it in advance [*grin*] ... get the listing, sort by the full name, use `Group-Object` to group what you want into logical bunches, and process those bunches.

Comment: The recursion built into `Get-ChildItem` doesn't do what you're asking, so you need to write your own recursive function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for manual recursion, `Get-ChildItem` will do what you want when you also use `Sort-Object` and `Select-Object`.

- `Get-ChildItem` with Recurse to get your item list
- `sort` by `FullName` to put the items in the order you want
- `select` the `Name` property to show just the items Name

Gives:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\folder -Recurse | sort FullName | select -ExpandProperty Name

Alpha
1.txt
2.txt
3
a.txt
b.txt
4.txt
Beta
Test
Another
file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually solved it before I got to see your post just now, but my solution also abused the FullName in a way not too dissimilar from your own once the eureka regarding the way that would sort appeared in my head. As such, I'll accept your answer! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Can be solved with a simple recursive wrapper function:

```
function Get-ChildItemDepthFirst
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Container})]
    [string]$LiteralPath = $PWD
  )

  foreach($item in Get-ChildItem @PSBoundParameters){
    # Output current item name
    $item.Name
    # Check to see if item is a folder, if so recurse
    if($item -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]){
      Get-ChildItemDepthFirst -LiteralPath $item.FullName
    }
  }
}
```

FWIW, I'd personally go for [James C.'s elegant approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54867870/712649)